# $A_1,\dots, A_n:V \rightarrow V$ are linear maps, and $\sigma=(1,2,\dots,n-1,n)$, then $tr(\otimes_i A_i \circ \sigma) = tr(A_n A_{n-1}\cdots A_1)$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, modules, tensor-products, tensors

Suppose $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space.

Let $A_1, \dots, A_n : V \rightarrow V$ be linear maps.

Now consider $\sigma : V^{\otimes n} \rightarrow V^{\otimes n}$ defined by $\sigma(v_1 \otimes v_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_n) = v_n \otimes v_1 \otimes \cdots \otimes v_{n-2} \otimes v_{n-1}$. This is the $(1, 2, \dots, n-1, n)$ cycle.

Using universal properties of tensor products this extends to a linear map $P:V^{\otimes n} \rightarrow V^{\otimes n}$.

Then if $tr$ means the trace, how can one see that:

$tr(A_1 \otimes A_2 \otimes \cdots \otimes A_n \circ P) = tr(A_nA_{n-1}\cdots A_1)$?

It looks intuitive enough it's just that I don't know enough trace properties or behaviors or intuitions for this.

Answer (score 1):

Just hammering out everything with respect to a basis $e_1,\dots,e_m$ of $V$ and its dual basis $\varepsilon^1,\dots,\varepsilon^m$ of $V^\vee$:
\begin{align*}
&((A_1\otimes A_2\otimes\dots\otimes A_n)P)(e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_n})\\
&=(A_1\otimes A_2\otimes\dots\otimes A_n)(P(e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_n}))\\
&=(A_1\otimes A_2\otimes\dots\otimes A_n)(e_{i_n}\otimes e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_{n-1}})\\
&=A_1(e_{i_n})\otimes A_2(e_{i_1})\otimes\dots\otimes A_n(e_{i_{n-1}})\\
&(\varepsilon^{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes\varepsilon^{i_n})((A_1\otimes A_2\otimes\dots\otimes A_n)P)(e_{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes e_{i_n})\\
&=(\varepsilon^{i_1}\otimes\dots\otimes\varepsilon^{i_n})(A_1(e_{i_n})\otimes A_2(e_{i_1})\otimes\dots\otimes A_n(e_{i_{n-1}}))\\
&=[\varepsilon^{i_1}(A_1(e_{i_n}))]
[\varepsilon^{i_2}(A_2(e_{i_1}))]\dots
[\varepsilon^{i_n}(A_n(e_{i_{n-1}}))]
\end{align*}
But obviously $\varepsilon^i(T(e_j))$ is just the $(i,j)$-entry of the matrix representing $T$ in the basis $\{e_1,\dots,e_m\}$.  So summing over $i_1,\dots,i_n$, we have
\begin{align*}
&\operatorname{tr}((A_1\otimes A_2\otimes\dots\otimes A_n)P)\\
&=\sum_{i_1,\dots,i_n}(A_1)_{i_1,i_n}(A_2)_{i_2,i_1}\dots(A_n)_{i_n,i_{n-1}}\\
&=\sum_{i_1,\dots,i_n}(A_n)_{i_n,i_{n-1}}\dots(A_2)_{i_2,i_1}(A_1)_{i_1,i_n}\\
&=\sum_{i_2,\dots,i_n}(A_n)_{i_n,i_{n-1}}\dots(A_2A_1)_{i_2,i_n}\\
&=\dots\\
&=\sum_{i_n}(A_n\dots A_2A_1)_{i_n,i_n}\\
&=\operatorname{tr}(A_n\dots A_2A_1).
\end{align*}